# How can I define a distribution and get the expectation in Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

How can I define a distribution and get the expectation in Mathematica for $a=a_H$ with probability $\lambda$ and $a=a_L$ with probability $1−\lambda$, where $\lambda\in(0,1)$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many ways.  Here's one:

```
dist = TransformedDistribution[x aH + (1 - x) aL, x \[Distributed] BernoulliDistribution[λ]]
Mean[dist]
(* aL+aH λ-aL λ *)
```

Answer (score 7):

As JimB notes, there are many ways. Here's another:

```
dist = EmpiricalDistribution[{\[Lambda], 1 - \[Lambda]} -> {aH, aL}];
Mean[dist]
(* aL (1 - \[Lambda]) + aH \[Lambda] *)
```